# Pointer assignment different behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers

Hi I tried the following code:

```
int *a=&matrice[4][0];
cout<<*a<<"\n\n";

int *b;
b = &matrice[4,4];
```

Where matrice is defined like this: `int matrice[5][5];` and I filled it with some normal int values.

The first assignment works but the second doesn't with the error :

`a value of type "int (*)[5]" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int * "` .

I expected both of them to give me an error at compile time.

Could you explain why there is this different behavior ?

Comment: ...because `matrice[4,4]` is the same as `matrice[4]` which is a `int(*)[5]` and not an `int*`? what more is there?

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect the first one to compile?

Comment: BTW the singular of _matrices_ is _matrix_, not "matrice".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression

```
&matrice[4,4]
```

does not do what you have expected, because the expression

```
4,4
```

evaluates to `4`. This is an example of the comma operator, which evaluates both operands and returns the second operand.

Answer (score 2):

`&matrice[4][0]` is of type `int *` and you are assigning it to `a` which is also of type `int *`. Nothing wrong in this. You will not get any type of error.

`matrice[4,4]` is not representing a 2D matrix rather it evaluates to `matrice[4]` because of the effect of the `,` operator and `&matrice[4]`is of type `int(*)[5]`.  Try this;

```
 b = &matrice[4][4];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are assigning a pointer address to `a`.  `matrice` is internally defined as a pointer to an array of pointers and you are getting the address of one such vector into `a`.

The second one is using the comma operator inside the index reference.  That is incorrect as well.

Comment: Is it really true that `matrice` is internally defined as a pointer to pointers? I would see that `matrice[2]` decays to a pointer but that is not the internal representation or is it.

Comment: @s.bandara Right, internally a 2D array is just a 1D array with fancy indexing, not an array of pointers. The elements are all in contiguous memory.